# How to improve performance when querying CustomMetadata's FieldDefinition fields

Tags: performance, custom-metadata, fielddefinition

When I query string columns on custom metadata objects, I get decent performance.  However, if I query a column that points to a FieldDefinition, my query became much slower.

Is this a known system bug?  Is there a patch on the horizon?

It makes these relationships really unusable.

Here are profiling logs on a sandbox. (I'll just include the SOQL profiling.):

Querying a String takes **19ms**.

```
for (My_Metadata__mdt m: [SELECT Id, String__c FROM My_Metadata__mdt]) {
    System.debug(m.id);
}
```

```
AnonymousBlock: line 1, column 1: [SELECT Id, String__c FROM My_Metadata__mdt]: executed 273 times in 19 ms
```

Query a FieldDefinition takes about **half a second**!

```
for (My_Metadata__mdt m: [SELECT Id, Field__c FROM My_Metadata__mdt]) {
    System.debug(m.id);
}
```

```
AnonymousBlock: line 1, column 1: [SELECT Id, Field__c FROM My_Metadata__mdt]: executed 273 times in 511 ms
```

#### Profiling Procedure:

1. Run a snippet ~10 times.
2. Note the times on each except the first are about the same.
3. Choose one of the middle-ground non-first logs to paste here.

Comment: Can you share more info on how you primed the pump? I'm surprised there would be that big a difference for a warm cache.

Comment: @CarolynGrabill Me too!  I ran the same code about 10 times.  For the both queries, the first time it was a bit slower, the rest of the queries had more or less the same performance.

Comment: I've reposted the question [in the Custom Metadata Type group](https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00003nTQch) and [SFDC developer forums](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9060G0000005ntzQAA)

Comment: See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/262147/7195 for a reasonably likely explanation for why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

5 years later and the same difference in speed can still be measured - I've just given it a try :-)

But things have improved, and the obvious answer to the question raised by the title is: not to query the database, but to access the application cache by the [methods provided by the "Custom Metadata Type" object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_custom_metadata_types.htm).

The loop could then look like this:

```
for (My_Metadata__mdt m: My_Metadata__mdt.getAll().values()) {
    System.debug(m.Field__c);
}
```

My tests indicate this is indeed faster than any of the afore SOQL.