# How to display the field label in combobox using lwc

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am using Apex class to fetch all the fields of the SObject. And i want to display all the field label into the component so i am using lwc to create a component Successfully ii am getting all the Case fields in the component but the field label is not visible

Below is the Apex code
// class 1

```
public class ComboBoxModel 
{
public  String fieldLabel;
public String fieldValue;


}
```

//Class 2

```
   public  class  GetEfilesUsingSOQLQuery {

     @AuraEnabled
   public static List<ComboBoxModel> fetchObjectFields(objectName)
     {
    List<ComboBoxModel> cbModels = new List<ComboBoxModel>();
    List<String> CustomlistViewFields = new List<String>();
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    Schema.SObjectType leadSchema = schemaMap.get(objectName);
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = leadSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();


    for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()) {

        System.debug('##Field API Name='+fieldName);// list of all field API name



        CustomlistViewFields.add(fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel());//It provides to get the object fields label.
    }
    for(String temp:  CustomlistViewFields){
    ComboBoxModel cbModel = new  ComboBoxModel();
        cbModel.fieldValue = temp;
        cbModel.fieldLabel = temp;
        cbModels.add(cbModel);
    }
    return cbModels;

}
```

}

Below is Html code

```
        <lightning-combobox
          name="Field Name"
          label="Field Name"
          placeholder="Choose Field"
          value={selectedFieldValue}
          onchange={handleFieldValueChange}
          options={FieldsName}>
```

Below is the js code

```
      handleOpenFilterModalBox()
        {

      getCustomListViewFields().then(data=>{
if(data)
{
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        console.log('id=' + data[i].fieldValue);
        this.FieldsName = [...this.FieldsName ,{value: data[i].fieldValue , label: data[i].fieldLabel}];                                   
    }                
}
this.dispatchEvent(
    new ShowToastEvent({
        title: 'Success!!'+this.FieldsName,
         message: '',
        variant: 'Success',
    }),
);
    }).catch(error=>{
this.dispatchEvent(
    new ShowToastEvent({
        title: 'Error!!'+error.message,
        message: '',
        variant: 'error',
    }),
     );
   })


    }
```

So tell me how to display the field label in the Combobox

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the [uiRecordApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_lightning_ui_api_record) getRecordUi to fetch this information efficiently and without the need to write your own server-side code? It has the benefit of presenting relevant schema details for the current user based on the assigned layout and permissions.

Comment: I would also suggest you avoid using the Schema.getGlobalDescribe API as this is notoriously expensive. Take a look at [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262146/how-to-improve-schema-access-performance/262147#262147) for more.

Comment: @PhilW Please tell me the  code  how to fetch the  object Fields label and value using uiRecordApi

Comment: Take a look at the [getRecordUi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_record_ui) documentation.

Comment: Follow the link to the [Record UI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_responses_record_ui.htm) description that takes you down to the [Field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_responses_field.htm#ui_api_responses_field) that includes the "label" property you want.

Comment: @PhilW I am not getting the relevant answer on the mentioned link.

Comment: When you get back a response from getRecordUi, its "data" is a Record UI instance. This contains objectInfos (you can query multiple record UI details in one go, so you get a different info object per record requested) and these contain the fields that each have a label.

Comment: Please can you write the code for that

Comment: Using  RecordUi i can only get the specified field labbel not all the fields label of the object