# How do I tell if a custom metadata type field is a Field Definition?

Tags: custom-metadata, describesobject, sobjecttype

I have the following code:

```
public static void getFields(){

    SObject obj = (SObject) Type.forName('Health_Cloud_Integration_Settings__mdt').newInstance();
    DescribeSObjectResult describe = obj.getSObjectType().getDescribe();
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = describe.fields.getMap();

    for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()) {
        //get all the fields label for Account Object
        String fieldLabel = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel();
        //get data types for each fields
        Schema.DisplayType fielddataType = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getType();
        System.debug(fieldLabel + ' | ' + fielddataType);
        // If fieldtype = field definition add api name to list of strings for soql 


}
```

However field data type returns string for my Field Definition type fields? How do I do this?

Comment: Just be aware that use of global describe and field definition custom metadata type fields are very slow (they use many 100s of milliseconds to process in a given request and this can be a significant issue if you are doing CPU intensive work in that same request). Take a look at [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262146/how-to-improve-schema-access-performance/262147#262147) for some details on this.

Comment: Thanks Phil. Really useful to know. I have updated my OP + Code.

Comment: Looking at the DescribeFieldResult, and confirming that a Field Definition is reported as being a STRING display type, I cannot see any way to detect that this is a Field Definition using the Schema API. Perhaps you could deal with this using a naming convention (so the Field Definition field API names are "*Field__c" for example)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of describe calls, query **FieldDefinition** object.

There is a field named **ExtraTypeInfo** that has information to indicate it is an ***externallookup*** and also the DataType is ***Picklist()***

The below code is tested in my Dev org and return the info .

```
for(FieldDefinition field: [Select Id, DataType, QualifiedApiName, ExtraTypeInfo from FieldDefinition where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName='Health_Cloud_Integration_Settings__mdt']){
   if(field.ExtraTypeInfo != null && field.ExtraTypeInfo=='externallookup' &&  field.DataType == 'Picklist()') {
       system.debug(field.QualifiedApiName);
  }
}
```