# how to use Custom Metadata for field mapping

Tags: apex, custom-metadata

I am working on oen of the project where I need to use custom metadata for field mapping, I have two objects

1. Structure__c
2. Agent__c

here structure is the parent and agent is the child object, whenever structure is updating then I need to capture old field values and needs to create record in agent object which can be achieved with trigger.
but now the issue is we want to give field mapping option to admin which I think can be done with custom metadata

Can anyone guide or example code to do field mapping dynamically with custom metadata please.

Comment: Sorry, can you provide an example of what you mean by give field mapping option to end user? Which fields?

Comment: Before you head off down this direction, please read [this previous Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/331547/how-to-use-custom-metadata-to-map-generic-json/331560#331560) where I discussed performance of Entity and Field reference loading in Apex.

Comment: @bpilling I mean to say we want to give option to admin to decide which fields need to copy from parent to child object

Comment: im able to achieve this, just need to create mapping in metadata the access that metadata inside class for field mapping